# Defining a property based on a parent's method in PHP

Tags: php, oop, methods, properties

```
class UserInfo extends Database{

    private $privileges=
        $this
            ->connect()
            ->select("users", "DISTINCT privileges", "username= 'someuser'")
            ->getResult('privileges');

}
```

It doesn't seem like it is possible for me to be able to define this property `$privileges` based on a method based on the parent class `Database`.

It is worth pointing out the same function works splendidly when I use the same function in a different script and define the properties dynamically. Each class is instantiated by an object, it works (obviously with the proper setters and getters.)

```
$db = new Database;
$user = new UserInfo;
$user-> privileges= 
    $db
        ->connect()
        ->select("users", "DISTINCT privileges", "username= '".$user->name."'")
        -> getResult('privileges');
```

Comment: This inheritance model just looks wrong.

Comment: I don't feel that comment is helpful. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put an expression when defining a property's value inside a class. Use the constructor for that:

```
<?php
class UserInfo extends Database
{
    // ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        // initialize the 'privileges' property
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The new instance (`this`) is not ready when the private members are initialized. You have to put that code into the constructor.